# How to check if the last character in a string is a certain character and remove it from string? (C++)

Tags: c++, string

I have this function to return whether the specified directory exists:

```
double directory_exists(char *pathname)
{
    struct stat sb;
    return (stat(pathname,&sb) == 0 &&
            S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode));
}
```

However, if the last character the user typed is a slash ("\" on Windows or "/" on Mac / Linux) I'd like to remove that character from the pathname and store that value in a new variable and use that variable in stat() instead of pathname.

stat() will think the path doesn't exist if there just so happens to be a slash at the end, and since some people, (not everyone), do think to put a slash at the end of their pathname, I'd like to cater to that by detecting whether they used a slash at the end and then remove it.

I'm looking for a portable solution for Windows / Mac / Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I think I should've searched more before asking here.

```
double directory_exists(char *pathname)
{
    std::string str(pathname);
    if (!str.empty())
    {
        while (*str.rbegin() == '\\' || *str.rbegin() == '/')
        {
            str.erase(str.size()-1);
        }
    }

    struct stat sb;
    return (stat((char *)str.c_str(),&sb) == 0 &&
            S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode));
}
```

What's nice about this approach is that it doesn't require C++11, unlike string::back() and string::pop_back().

Comment: you are right to think that you could have achieved that without asking here, but now please accept your own answer to this question so that it's clear that the problem is solved

Comment: @slawekwin I was going to but it says I have to wait 2 days. I'll do it when I'm able. :)

Comment: You shouldn't take the address of a literal string. Just do a char comparison:  `*str.rbegin() == '\\' || *str.rbegin() == '/'`

Comment: @DarioP Thanks for the tip! :)